# Internet Explorer Compatible CSS Filter Generator

Tags: css, internet-explorer, filter

I am looking to write image filter declarations in IE syntax and was wondering if anyone could recommend one of those css generators that also writes to IE in addition to web-kit and filter?

In any case, the following are the properties that I am looking to replicate in IE:

```
    filter: grayscale(1) contrast(1) brightness(1);
    mix-blend-mode: luminosity;
    opacity:.5;

    filter: invert(42%) sepia(39%) saturate(2795%) hue-rotate(350deg) 
    brightness(100%) contrast(90%);
```

Any help translating any of these properties or directing me to literature would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [this autoprefixer](https://autoprefixer.github.io/) by ymatuhin for a quick and easy way to prefix your code.

There is also a [good article by Prefixr](http://prefixr.com/what-are-vendor-prefixes.php) on all of the vendor prefixes and why they are used.

Answer (score 0):

grayscale don't work with IE

You can look [this page](https://www.karlhorky.com/2012/06/cross-browser-image-grayscale-with-css.html)

I think you can add, just for IE, a div in absolute position covering element with background with opacity.